# FullScreen for SurfaceView not working in lollipop or higher

Tags: android, surfaceview

I created surfaceView like this.

content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.networks.streaming.surfaceviewfullscreentest.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <SurfaceView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/liveSurfaceView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
 @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    SurfaceView liveSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.liveSurfaceView);    
    liveSurfaceView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
        );
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
  }
```

this code works in android devices running Kitkat (API 19). but when I run the same code on devices running lollipop or higher the resultant display is like this.

[image]

the uper and lower borders are visible and surfaceView does not cover full screen. how can I fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is Example !!!

```
  <application android:allowBackup="true"   

    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"     
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
   <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Add to style.xml

```
  <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>

</style>
```

Comment: how to fullscreen in lollipop and higher? as system bar and  navigation bar are still visible.

Comment: Use Theme NoActiBar.FullScreen

Comment: @android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen

Comment: it is still not working. I am using AppCompatActivity as parent class. That requires me to use AppComp theme or decedent of it.